# Go to specific activity when notification received in closed application?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Below is my code, it works perfectly while app is in background but it gets to splash screen when app is not in background;

```
 Intent resultIntent = null;
    if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("refer_friend")) {
        resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyLoyaltyHistoryActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("key", "2");
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    }


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I think you should check if your app is in foreground then create notification only means no need to set any activity in intent OR else you can't generate notification

Comment: my application is totally closed...want to check in close app not also in stack .

Comment: Strange use case. Any way I just know about whether your app is in background OR not and that way you can handle case. I don't know much more about how to find whether your app is in close app stack or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer by using `TaskStackBuilder`

Used below code;

```
  Intent resultIntent = null;

    if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("refer_friend")) {
        resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReferFreindLoyaltyActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("back_flag", "1");
        resultIntent.putExtra("refer_a_freind", "1");
    }

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yu_android);
    }


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not in the background then you can get the JSON data that was sent in data payload with notification as follows:

Just add this line of code in your **SplashActivity.java**:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String pushType = bundle.getString("push_type");
```

Inside bundle, you will get all the key value data that you were sending from your backend. Here in my case, I am sending the **push_type** key in the data payload, that is received in my case you can also get your key here in **SplashActivity.java**.